# Alternate access problem

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, alternate-access-mapping

I have alternate access set for my site like

default : `http://mycomputername`

intranet: `http://192.168.XX.XX`

internet: `http://204.xx.xx.xx:portnumber`

I have problem from accessing it from internet
Problem # 1
Like when I type the internet address from the above list it doesnt shows up the site until I type the /default.aspx to it. 
Problem # 2
The links generated on the site page doesnt have to port number

Let me know
Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm the bindings in IIS have the same settings?

Comment: Bindings are : 
http - 80 - * , 
http - 80 - 192.168.xx.xx , 
http - 888 - 204.xx.xx.xx

Comment: Could you post the output of this command:Get-SPAlternateUrl? If that's SharePoint 2010 of course...

Comment: Incoming: http://mycomputername:3232    Zone: Default         Public: http://mycomputername:3232

Comment: Incoming: http://mycomputername        Zone: Default         Public: http://mycomputername

Comment: Incoming: http://192.168.10.253    Zone: Intranet    Public:   http://192.168.10.253

Comment: Incoming: http://204.81.208.66:888    Zone: Internet      Public:  http://204.81.208.66:888

Comment: Above comments are from the output

Comment: Do you use a load balancer?